# How to actually prove that the user consented to data processing while he submitted the form?

Tags: django, gdprconsentform

A user submits a form and opts in to receive a newsletter. What do I need to do to prove later that he actually did opt in?

If I store submitted form data in a db table then I am able to manually create and modify entries, so I could just change his `False` to `True` and therefore db entries don't prove anything.

I have a django website if it makes any difference.

Comment: Who do you have to prove it to and why? Most logging/record keeping solutions could probably be falsified with enough effort

Comment: To supervisory authority, if the customer files a complaint, so for example ICO (Information Commisioner's Office) in the UK.

Comment: Or if I use the sign up form to "sign a contract" with the customer. He gives me his credit card number and I charge it for appropriate amount. Then he claims he didn't sign the contract. So I must be able to prove that he did in fact submit the form which signed the contract according to TOS.

Comment: 1) you should have logging that writes somewhere that you can't edit so it's read-only to you. Log all important actions and events 2) You should not have access to the production DB at all, the fact that you can access/edit it leaves you wide open for all kinds of accusations. Make life easy for yourself and refuse to ever have access unless it's an emergency and you are supervised. 3) Get someone from security to sign off on your compliance and hand over responsibility to them

Comment: I am the sole creator of my company's website and I am a vice president of the company. How can I not have access to production DB if I am the main/only developer? It sounds to me like hiding your apartment key from yourself and then trying to forget where you hid it :/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a table that just logs these kinds of events. The respective table might contain a datetime column, a user ID column and the Boolean value that the `user_opt_in` field was changed to.

Comment: Yeah but theoretically I can insert a row manually that was not created automatically. Therefore the existence of a row in a log doesn't prove that the user really submitted the form. And in case of a dispute I have a motif to do such a thing, so that wouldn't be trustworthy.